# Update Java Exception List

Tags: powershell

I need to add URL to Java exception sites. I found a way to add using powershell but i need to add only if the url is not yet added.

i tried the following code below. but it always adds. i need to add the URL only if it does not exist.

```js
$site = "somesite.com"
Add-Content -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\exception.sites" -Value "$site"
```

the specified URL is added only if it does not exist in the list already

Comment: As the site file looks to be a simple text list with just one URL per line, you could load it with `Get-Content`, then look for the new URL in the content (say, by filtering with `Where-Object`) and add it if it's not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$javafile = "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\exception.sites"
$site = 'somesite.com'
if (! (select-string -quiet $site $javafile)) {
  Add-Content $javafile $site
}
```

Note that using >> or out-file would encode the line in unicode and break it.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested to inject an exception list into the java exception file , here's another code sample

```
$javafile = "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\exception.sites"
$exceptionfileSource = "\\myserver\share\exception.sites"
$MyFile = get-content $exceptionfileSource

foreach ($line in $Myfile){
    Write-Host $line
     if (! (select-string -quiet $line $javafile)) {
            Add-Content $javafile $line
        }
```